# When using MVC in PHP,Should 1 Controller be able to load a entire dynamic user profile?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, model, controller

Im almost scared to ask questions around here these days because I useually get flammed on and told my question is dumb, but here it goes anyways...

Im new to MVCs and im starting to get the hang of them, but one thing im unsure about is if 1 controller is suppose to load a entire profile that has multiple components (i.e a notification beacon, a friend feed, a list of friends that displays thumbnails , a place to post statuses ect...)for the purposes of this post assume im asking if alll the loading for a entire facebook profile should be done in one controller?

Or do i separate each dynamic component into its own MVC and then glue them all together in one main controller or....?

another idea i had was that maybe u do separate each component , but instead of having one main controller you call them as needed in the index.

Comment: I think you mean to say View instead of Controller...

Answer (score 0):

You could use one controller for the Profile (using your example) and have multiple models fetch and process all the data you need to show. This way even a big page can result in an easy to understand controller that is not so big.

Comment: Is that the standard?Are any of the other ways u mentioned ever acceptable? and if so whats the difference between a library and a controller?